# display progress of robocopy script on shutdown

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy, gpo

I've setup a Robocopy script that runs on computer shutdown for the domain users on our network.  The idea is to backup user folders to a NAS in case the user isn't using the mapped network drives for office data.

I'm not using folder redirection or roaming profiles because the data isn't mission critical and I don't want the delays of syncing folders during startup.  And there are just some things that are best run locally rather than from a network.

So the user finishes, shuts down their computer and the script runs in the background.  The thing is that some of the staff, being diligent workers, hang around to make sure the computer shut down correctly and the poor staff stand there thinking the computer has frozen while the script is backing data.

Is there a way to have the script below show the progress of the file copy?
And maybe even a message that says "Your user profile is being backed up.  The computer will complete the shutdown process when the backup is finished."

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

Set day=%DATE:~7,2%
Set mm=%DATE:~4,2%
Set dd=%DATE:~7,2%
Set yyyy=%DATE:~10,4%
Set RCLogFile=C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_FileSync-Log.txt

SET _what=/MIR /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T
 :: /COPY:DAT :: COPY ALL file info
 :: /COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info
 :: /B :: copy files in Backup mode. 
 :: /MIR :: MIRror a directory tree 

SET _options=/R:0 /W:1 /FP /NDL /NP /TEE /XF "desktop.ini" ".DS_Store" "._Temporary Items" "._TemporaryItems" "*..RF" "thumbs.db" /XD ".AppleFileInfo" "Network Trash Folder" "TheFindByContentFolder" "TheVolumeSettingsFolder" "Temporary Items" "TemporaryItems"
 :: /R:n :: number of Retries
 :: /W:n :: Wait time between retries
 :: /LOG :: Output log file
 :: /NDL :: No directory logging
 :: /NP :: No % percentage logging

MD C:\backup-logs 
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Contacts" H:\Computer_Backup\Contacts %_what% %_options% /LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Desktop" H:\Computer_Backup\Desktop %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Documents" H:\Computer_Backup\Documents %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Downloads" H:\Computer_Backup\Downloads %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Favorites" H:\Computer_Backup\Favorites %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Links" H:\Computer_Backup\Links %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Music" H:\Computer_Backup\Music %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\Pictures" H:\Computer_Backup\Videos %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook" H:\Computer_Backup\Roaming\Outlook %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures" H:\Computer_Backup\Roaming\Signatures %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word" H:\Computer_Backup\Roaming\Word %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" H:\Computer_Backup\Local\Outlook %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
ROBOCOPY "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google" H:\Computer_Backup\Roaming\Google %_what% %_options% /+LOG:"C:\backup-logs\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%_-_shutdown-backup.txt"
```

Comment: How do you start the script -- via Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: GPO User Logoff Script

Comment: I think the script runs hidden in that case; perhaps you could try to use a logoff script that contains only `start "" /WAIT cmd /C "\path\to\your\copy_script.bat"` which in turn calls the script in your question; I believe that it is visible then...